# What is the description and attribute of Maa Kali?

Tags: kali, ramakrishna

It is well known fact that Ramakrishna Paramahams saw and talked with mother Kali. She use to pamper him like a child and sometimes he use to feed prasadam to her. I suspect, if we are lucky enough to have any description of attributes of maa Kali by Ramakrishna Paramahams, that is, how maa Kali appeared to be or how does she looks?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [Sri Ramakrishna the Great Master](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/) by Swami Saradananda (Translated from Bengali by Swami Jagadananda)

It seems that the great Master, Sri Ramakrishna Paramhamsa experienced the Divine Mother, goddess Mahakali, both in the Nirguna-Nirakar, and Saguna-Sakara aspects.

> #### 6) [SPIRITUAL EAGERNESS AND THE FIRST VISION](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/sriramakrishna_thegreatmaster/srkgrtmaster_files/Sri%20Ramakrishna%20-%20The%20Great%20Master-18.html)
>
> - ##### 13. The description of the Master’s attainment of the first vision of the universal Mother. The Master’s yearning at that time
>
> He used to say, “There was then an intolerable anguish in my heart
> because I could not have Her vision. Just as a man wrings a towel
> forcibly to squeeze out all the water from it, I felt as if somebody
> caught hold of my heart and mind and was doing so with them. Greatly
> afflicted with the thought that I might never have Mother’s vision, I
> was dying of despair. Being in an agony I thought that there was then
> no use in living this life. My eyes suddenly fell upon the sword that
> was there in the Mother’s temple. I made up my mind to put an end to
> my life with it that very moment. Like one mad, I ran and caught hold
> of it, when suddenly I had the wonderful vision of the Mother, and
> fell down unconscious. I did not know what happened then in the
> external world—how that day and the next slipped away. But, in my
> heart of hearts, there was flowing a current of intense bliss, never
> experienced before, and
>
> I had the immediate knowledge of the Light that was Mother.”
>
> On another occasion the Master described to us in detail his wonderful
> vision spoken of before. He said, “It was as if houses, doors, temples
> and all other things vanished altogether; as if there was nothing
> anywhere! **And what I saw was a boundless infinite conscious sea of
> light!** However far and in whatever direction I looked, I found a
> contiuous succession of effulgent waves coming forward, raging and
> storming from all sides with a great speed. Very soon they fell on me
> and made me sink to the unknown bottom. I panted, struggled, and fell
> unconscious.” **The Master told us that at the time of his first vision
> he saw a conscious sea of light. But what about the divine Mother’s
> form consisting of pure consciousness only — the form of Hers with
> hands that give boons and freedom from fear? Did the Master then have
> the vision of that form also in that sea of light? It appears that he
> had, for as soon as he had the slightest consciousness at the time of
> his first vision, he, we are told, uttered repeatedly the word
> “Mother” in a plaintive voice.**
>
> When that vision came to an end, there arose in the heart of the
> Master an eager, incessant cry of lamentation for a constant immediate
> vision of the divine Mother’s form, consisting of consciousness only.
> Although it was not always manifested in external symptoms like
> weeping, etc., it always existed in his heart. Sometimes it increased
> so much that, unable to suppress it, he fell on the ground and
> struggled in pain. He wept so much, saying, “Bestow Thy grace on me
> Mother, show Thyself to me,” that people gathered all round him! Even
> a shade of a concern for what they would think of such restlessness
> did not arise in his mind at that time. He used to say, “Although
> people stood all round, they appeared unreal like shadows or pictures
> painted on canvas, and the slightest sense of shame or hesitation did
> not touch the mind on that account. But immediately after I lost
> consciousness on account of unbearable anguish, **I saw that form of the
> Mother with hands that give boons and freedom from fear —the form that
> smiled, spoke and consoled and taught me in endless ways!”**

> #### 7) [SADHANA AND DIVINE INEBRIATION](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/sriramakrishna_thegreatmaster/srkgrtmaster_files/Sri%20Ramakrishna%20-%20The%20Great%20Master-19.html)
>
> - ##### 3.  What changes were produced in all his actions and ideas by the first vision
>
> The Master’s worship, meditation, etc., underwent novel changes. It is
> difficult to explain to others that wonderful state of complete
> absorption in Her...
>
> ....
>
> Whenever one saw him, one thought that he had merged his little will
> and the little ego, in the will of Her who was the source of all
> wills, and did everything as if he was completely an instrument in Her
> hand, praying in his heart of hearts, “Mother, my only refuge, kindly
> make me, Thy boy, say and do what I should.”
>
> .....
>
> Although in the world, he was not of it. The external world was now
> transformed for him into a dream world. Now he could not attribute
> reality to it in spite of efforts. **The universal Mother’s form,
> consisting of pure consciousness and bliss, was now known to him as
> the only reality.**
>
> ---
>
> - ##### 4. The difference between the previous worship, vision, etc., of the Master and those of this time
>
> Previously, on some occasions at the time of worship and meditation,
> the Master used to see a hand of the divine Mother or a foot, bright
> and delicate, or Her sweet, affectionate and smiling face, supremely
> beautiful. **Now he saw, even at times other than those of worship and
> meditation, the full figure of the effulgent Mother, smiling and
> speaking, guiding and accompanying him and saying, “Do this, don’t do
> that.”**
>
> Formerly when he offered cooked food etc., to the Mother, he used to
> see an extraordinary ray of light coming out beaming from Her eyes,
> touching all the offered articles, taking their essential parts and
> withdrawing itself again into Her eyes. **Now he saw that even before
> the offering was made, the same Mother in Her very person, sat down to
> take the offerings illumining the temple with the effulgence of Her
> holy presence.** One day Hriday came suddenly at the time of the
> worship and saw that the Master had taken in his hands an Arghya
> consisting of china-roses and Vilva leaves, which he was going to
> offer at the lotus feet of the divine Mother. He was absorbed in
> thinking of Her, when he cried out suddenly saying, “Wait, wait. Let
> me utter the Mantra first; and then Thou mayst take it.” He then
> offered the food ritually before finishing the worship.
>
> Previously, at the time of worship and meditation, he saw that there
> appeared a wonderful living Presence in the stone image before him.
> Now he did not see that image at all when he entered the temple; **but
> saw instead, standing there, the living Mother Herself, all
> consciousness, and with hands that offered boons and freedom from
> fear. The Master said, “I put the palm of my hand near Her nostrils
> and felt that Mother was actually breathing. I observed very closely,
> but I could never see the shadow of the Mother’s divine person on the
> temple wall in the light of the lamp at night.** I heard from my room
> Mother, merry like a little girl, going upstairs, Her anklets making
> jingling sounds. I came out to verify and found that She, with Her
> hair dishevelled, was actually standing on the verandah of the first
> floor of the temple and was now viewing Calcutta, now the Ganga.”
>
> ---
>
> - ##### 12.  With the development of devotion, the Master’s external worship dropped off. His predicament at this time
>
> Always beside himself in spiritual moods, he served the universal
> Mother whensoever and howsoever he liked. For instance, he sometimes
> offered food before performing the worship; or, absorbed in meditation
> he forgot completely the idea of his separate existence from Her and
> decorated his own person with the flowers, sandal-paste, etc., brought
> for the worship of the goddess. We were told by the Master himself
> that on many occasions his actions assumed this form by virtue of his
> constant vision of the divine Mother inside and outside. And we were
> further told that, if that mood of his losing himself in Her decreased
> a little and if he was prevented from seeing the Mother even for a
> short time, such an overwhelming restlessness came on him that he
> threw himself violently on the ground, rubbing his face against it and
> filling the quarters with vehement wailings. He struggled for life and
> his breath was about to stop. He could take no notice of the fact that
> his whole body was getting cut and bruised and covered with blood. He
> was equally unaware whether he stumbled on fire or into water.
> Immediately afterwards, when he got the vision of the Mother, that
> mental attitude of his vanished, and his face beamed wonderfully with
> joy, and he became a different person, so to say.

So, from the above two excerpts, we may conclude, Sri Ramakrishna Paramhamsa had divine vision of Mother Goddess in both attributeless-formless aspects, and the with attributes & with form aspects also.